# Help with java script - to validate the files in a folder

Tags: javascript

I have got a html web page which gets a user input in the form of a directory path in a text box. I need to provide a validate button near the text box. on clicking the button, the user should get the feedback as to whether the directory path contains the required set of files, like few images and other files in certain format. Also i would have to read certain text files in the folder to determine if the image files listed in those are also located in the folder. I dont know web programming. can i do this in java script or in any other language? The directory is located in a local netwrok share. iam not aware of the security restrictions et al. please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. (It would be a security problem if websites could access local files.)

Answer (score 1):

To gain access to local files, you would have to use a language like Java, Microsoft Silverlight or maybe Adobe Flash. A corresponding applet could verify the validity of those files.